# Interpolate Nulls in google graph

Tags: javascript, graph, interpolation

I use google's chart javascript api to show some data. The data contains "0" / "null" values.

```
//...
totalpt1.setValue(154, 2, 1310799);
totalpt1.setValue(155, 2, 1313905);
totalpt1.setValue(156, 2, null);
totalpt1.setValue(157, 2, 1320264);
totalpt1.setValue(158, 2, 1323102);
//...

var chart11 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_totalpostthreads'));
chart11.draw(totalpt, {width: 600, height: 340, interpolateNulls:true, legend: 'bottom', title: 'Total Posts'});
```

The result is this:
[image: graph]

I have set interpolateNulls to true. But the graph is still not "smoothed". How can I prevent those single drop outs? I thought this is what the interpolate option was for...

Answer (score 2):

Null and 0 are different values.

Comment: I have replace the zero with "null" in the javascript output. It's an improvement, but intrapolation is still not working. See updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`totalpt1.setValueNull(156, 2);`